# osx brew mysqld ignoring configuration files

Tags: macos, mysql, homebrew

installed mysql 8.0.17 via brew on osx 10.14.6

When i start mysqld (either directly or via `brew services start mysql`) i can see mysql process listening on both 127.0.0.1 and `*`.

The `brew install` output clearly mentioned that it would listen on localhost only.

The only config file i could find `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` seems to be set that way:

```
$ cat /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

yet:

```
$ lsof -nP -i | grep LISTEN
mysqld    123 user   28u  IPv4 0x77334cb9760b9455      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3306 (LISTEN)
mysqld    123 user   31u  IPv6 0x77334cb96cd76ed5      0t0  TCP *:33060 (LISTEN)
```

i tried using `mysqld --verbose` but it doesn't mention which file is being used for config at all.

there is only that one mysql version installed. Confirmed by `which` and `find`.

Comment: I filed a bug report for this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96952

Comment: thanks! meanwhile got the patch for brew merged https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/42570

Answer (score 1):

it seems that is some sort of mysqlx plugin. not sure what that is used for or why it is enabled by default:

```
$ mysqld --verbose --help  | grep bind

bind-address                                                 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address                                          *
```

After adding `mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to my `my.cnf` lsof shows mysql listening only on localhost.